# Data Migration Tool Error: Base Table not Found

Tags: magento2, data-migration-tool

I need help really I am this close to data migration but I am getting following error. I am migrating data from 1.9.3.6 to 2.2.5

My database tables have prefix "mg_", I tried adding prefix command, it still not working

```
  [Zend_Db_Statement_Exception]
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db_mage11.core_config_data' doesn't exist, query was: SELE
  CT COUNT(*) FROM `core_config_data`

  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db_mage12.core_config_data' doesn't exist
```

[image]

Config Xml is this (removing DB credential)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xs:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../config.xsd">
    <steps mode="settings">
        <step title="Settings Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Settings\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Settings\Data</data>
        </step>
        <step title="Stores Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Stores\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Stores\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Stores\Volume</volume>
        </step>
    </steps>
    <steps mode="data">
        <step title="Data Integrity Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\DataIntegrity\Integrity</integrity>
        </step>
        <step title="EAV Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Eav\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Eav\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Eav\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Customer\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Customer\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Map Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Map\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Map\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Url Rewrite Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Log Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Log\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Log\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Log\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Ratings Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Ratings\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Ratings\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Ratings\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="ConfigurablePrices step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="OrderGrids Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Tier Price Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="SalesIncrement Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="PostProcessing Step">
            <data>Migration\Step\PostProcessing\Data</data>
        </step>
    </steps>
    <steps mode="delta">
        <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\Customer\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Map Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\Map\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Log Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\Log\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Log\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="OrderGrids Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="SalesIncrement Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>
        </step>
    </steps>
    <source>
        <database host="localhost" name="" user="" password="" />
    </source>
    <destination>
        <database host="localhost" name="" user="" password="" />
    </destination>

    <options>
        <map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.3.6/map.xml.dist</map_file>
        <eav_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-eav.xml.dist</eav_map_file>
        <eav_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/eav-document-groups.xml.dist</eav_document_groups_file>
        <eav_attribute_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/eav-attribute-groups.xml.dist</eav_attribute_groups_file>
        <log_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-log.xml.dist</log_map_file>
        <log_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/log-document-groups.xml.dist</log_document_groups_file>
        <settings_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/settings.xml.dist</settings_map_file>
        <customer_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-customer.xml.dist</customer_map_file>
        <customer_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/customer-document-groups.xml.dist</customer_document_groups_file>
        <customer_attribute_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/customer-attribute-groups.xml.dist</customer_attribute_groups_file>
        <delta_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/deltalog.xml.dist</delta_document_groups_file>
        <order_grids_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/order-grids-document-groups.xml.dist</order_grids_document_groups_file>
        <map_document_groups>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-document-groups.xml.dist</map_document_groups>
        <class_map>etc/opensource-to-opensource/class-map.xml.dist</class_map>
        <tier_price_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.3.4/map-tier-price.xml.dist</tier_price_map_file>
        <stores_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-stores.xml.dist</stores_map_file>
        <!--
        In case bulk_size=0 it will be auto-detected for every document.
        -->
        <bulk_size>0</bulk_size>
        <!--
        Set direct_document_copy = 1 for better performance.
        NOTE: 'source' and 'destination' databases MUST be placed on the same MySQL instance
        and 'destination' user MUST be granted with 'SELECT' permissions on 'source' database
         -->
        <direct_document_copy>0</direct_document_copy>
         <source_prefix>mg_</source_prefix>
        <dest_prefix />mg_<dest_prefix />
        <auto_resolve_urlrewrite_duplicates>0</auto_resolve_urlrewrite_duplicates>
        <log_file>migration.log</log_file>
        <progress_bar_format>%percent%% [%bar%] Remaining Time: %remaining%</progress_bar_format>
        <upgrade_customer_password_hash>1</upgrade_customer_password_hash>
        <edition_migrate>opensource-to-opensource</edition_migrate>
        <edition_number>1.9.3.6</edition_number>
        <init_statements_source>SET NAMES utf8;</init_statements_source>
        <init_statements_destination>SET NAMES utf8;</init_statements_destination>
        <crypt_key />
    </options>
</config>
```

Comment: Try removing underscore from db name. Refer to issue - https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/issues/270

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?  I am having a similar issue only on the `catalog_product_entity_int` table which the data migration tool seems to be trying to query without the db table prefix.

Comment: Hi @sanyazahid can u help me on this  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/289860/magento-2-data-migration-triggers-table-missing-in-m1