# Magento 2 data migration triggers table missing in M1

Tags: magento2, data-migration, table

We have successfully migrated data from M1 to M2 using the data migration tool. We have a custom table called  **md_cybersource** which is mapped to **magedelight_cybersource** in **map.xml**

When we run delta migration getting below error message

```
' Base table not found 1146 table m1_compressed.m2_cl_md_cybersource'  doesn't exist query was m2_cl_md_cybersource where ('processed'=1)

Base table view not found 1146 table m1_compressed.m2_cl_md_cybersource doesn't exit'
```

Observation is Searched trigger table in M1 which is not created. Please suggest or advise how to fix & why it is happen?

Answer (score 1):

We have 2options for that

**First** : try with ignore documents in `map.xml`

```
<source>
    <document_rules>
        <ignore>
            <document>magedelight_cybersource</document>
        </ignore>
</source>
```

**Second** : its tricky solution 
    **export only table ( not data )** from m1 and import in m2 like : `m2_cl_md_cybersource` than try with delta command.

**Try with above options its work for you**

Comment: actually, for the custom tables data migration tool needs are to create a triggers table at the time of data migration am I correct?

Comment: yes, if you create table in m2 than error not found.

Answer (score 0):

> in map.xml file

```
<source>
    <document_rules>
        ...
        <!-- Ignore `magedelight_cybersource` table -->
        <ignore>
            <document>magedelight_cybersource</document>
        </ignore>
        ...
</source>
```

I hope so it's useful for you.

Comment: actually I have to map this table (md_cybersource) to magedelight_cybersource that i already did in the map.xml its working as expected. but when i execute delta i found there is no table was created in m1 db with m2_cl_md_cybersource.

Answer (score 0):

Reason - It contains Prefix 'm1_'.

Solution - we need to add  for resolve this error.

**Ex: `<source_prefix>m1_</source_prefix>`**

Comment: so by adding only prefix for source will resolve the error? or we must add same prefix for destination also?

Comment: yes exactly!! if you want you can add prefix for destination also but if you leave it blank, this will use without prefix names.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the issue and resolved it by adding the below piece of code in the below-mentioned file.

```
<document key="card_id">md_cybersource</document>
```

**File Name:** **vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/commerce-to-commerce/1.14.3.1/deltalog.xml**

Syntax:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<groups xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xs:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../groups.xsd">
    <group name="delta_map">
               <document key="card_id">md_cybersource</document>
   </group>
  </groups>
```

So that it has been creating an **m2_cl_md_cybersource** triggers/data table at the time data migration in the M1 database.